# steam or steam-installer?

Tags: apt, 18.04, games, steam

I want to install steam to play games on my machine, `sudo apt search steam` gives me:

```
...
steam/bionic 1:1.0.0.54+repack-5ubuntu1 i386
  Valve's Steam digital software delivery system

steam-devices/bionic,bionic 1:1.0.0.54+repack-5ubuntu1 all
  Device support for Steam-related hardware

steam-installer/bionic,bionic 1.0.0.54+repack-5ubuntu1 all
  Installer for Valve's Steam digital software delivery system
...
```

So when should one use **steam** and when should one use **steam-installer**?

Comment: Just download Steam from the official website. This way you'll get the latest steam updates without having to wait for the next Ubuntu update since Steam adds it's own repository to your system.

Comment: @DanielMassey I agree with you, why not post this as an answer?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I didn't think it actually *answered* the author's question - it was just an *alternative*. But you have done so and he accepted it so cleary it was answer-worthy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download the `steam_latest.deb` from the official [website](https://store.steampowered.com/about/) and install it (using `gdebi` if you like) you will end up with `steam-launcher` installed and a Steam ppa added.

Answer (score 3):

`steam-installer` just installs `steam`. The Ubuntu Software store will only show you 64bit programs if you're on a 64bit OS. So `steam-installer` is just a workaround to show it in Ubuntu Software since `steam` is 32bit

Answer (score 0):

It appears the first option of:

```
steam/bionic 1:1.0.0.54+repack-5ubuntu1 i386
```

is the 32bit version and the other is the 64bit version so pick based on your OS

Comment: You sure? Seems like `steam` is just steam 32bit installed through apt while `steam-installer` is a separate 64bit installer installed through apt which  _then_ installs steam 32bit..